# Create multiple divs dynamically inside ajax success function based on the amount of data inside json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wish to create div elements dynamically inside ajax success with each div element having its id as the "id" from response data! is there any way to do that? could some one help me please! i have attached a code pen snipped below of my work so far too.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxXvbb?editors=1111#anon-login

```
  window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "get", 
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
           url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=05b5e7574eac47fdf8f2ac12831493c6&language=en-US&page=1", //url to send to 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) { 
                // console.log(msg);

                   for(var i = 0; i < msg.results.length; i++)
   {
let idx=msg.results[i].id
let titlex=msg.results[i].title;
let imagesrcx=msg.results[i].poster_path;
   console.log("ID: " +idx); 
   console.log("title: "+titlex);
   console.log("image src: "+imagesrcx);

   let new_div ='<div><div id="'+ idx +'">'+'</div></div>';

            $("main").append(new_div);
   //console.log(msg);
   }

            }

});

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use document.createElement? Seems the easiest way do dynamically create and set id, no need for jQuery here.

```
   for(var i = 0; i < msg.results.length; i++){
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = msg.results[i].id;
        $("#main").append(div);
    }
```

You can now use it with jQuery. If you want to add text to it, just also set `innerText`.

Here the complete code:
window.onload = function() {

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "get", 
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
           url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=05b5e7574eac47fdf8f2ac12831493c6&language=en-US&page=1", //url to send to 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) { 
                // console.log(msg);

              for(var i = 0; i < msg.results.length; i++) {
                 let idx=msg.results[i].id
                 let titlex=msg.results[i].title;
                 let imagesrcx=msg.results[i].poster_path;
                 console.log("ID: " +idx); 
                 console.log("title: "+titlex);
                 console.log("image src: "+imagesrcx);

                 const new_div = document.createElement('div');
                 new_div.id = idx;
                 new_div.innerText = titlex;

                $("#main").append(new_div);
              }
            }
    });
};
```

Working stackblitz;
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLyGOY)

EDIT: I also realized you forgot to add the '#' to select the main div, which might help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery,   in your success callback

```
msg.results.forEach((e)=>{
    const div = $(`<div id=${e.id}>${e.title}</div>`);
    $("#main").append(div);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
#main>div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "get", 
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
           url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=05b5e7574eac47fdf8f2ac12831493c6&language=en-US&page=1", //url to send to 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) { 
                   for(var i = 0; i < msg.results.length; i++)
   {
                     // console.log(msg);


let idx=msg.results[i].id
let titlex=msg.results[i].title;
let imagesrcx=msg.results[i].poster_path;
     console.log(imagesrcx);
$("#main").append(`
<div style='background:#000;' id='`+idx+`'>
  <img src='`+imagesrcx+`' alt='`+titlex+`'>
</div>
`);
   //console.log(msg);
   }

            }

});

};
```